# Angular variable output if/else HTML output not working

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm confused. I'm trying to check in a loop if the outputted key is a mail key, if yes, I want to wrap the output into a `<a>` tag to make the email clickable. Somehow it's not working and it's printing the whole content inside the div:

```
<div>{{contactInfo.key === 'mail_outline' ? '<a href="' + contactInfo.value + '">' + contactInfo.value + '</a>' : contactInfo.value}}</div>
```

Current result on the page:

```
{{contactInfo.key === 'mail_outline' ? '' + contactInfo.value + '' : contactInfo.value}}
```

I'm not sure if I understood the whole thing correctly. I'm coming from PHP and there I can do something like this. Can someone please explain me my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you surround the html elements inside the `div` with quotes like you did, you are telling angular that the `div`content is actually a text value. So it will end up displaying your condition as text.

You can add dynamic html by binding to `innerHtml` property like suggested, however I find it cleaner to keep display logic in the template using one of the options below.  Besides, they will avoid the extra overhead of calling a function every round of change detection

***ngIf**

```
<div >
  <a *ngIf="contactInfo.key === 'mail_outline'" href="{{contactInfo.value}}">{{contactInfo.value}}</a>
  <ng-container *ngIf="contactInfo.key !== 'mail_outline'">{{contactInfo.value}}</ng-container>
</div>
```

Or use ***ngSwitch**, which will be more adequate if you've got several different cases

```
  <div [ngSwitch]="contactInfo.key">
    <a *ngSwitchCase="'mail_outline'" href="{{contactInfo.value}}">{{contactInfo.value}}</a>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>{{contactInfo.value}}</ng-container>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use angular Html binding. Update your html

```
<div [innerHtml]="getLink()"></div>
```

In your typescript

```
getLink(){
 if(this.contactInfo.key === 'mail_outline')
 {
   return `<a href='${this.contactInfo.value}'>${this.contactInfo.value}</a>`;
 }
 else
 {
   return this.contactInfo.value;
 }
}
```

Thanks.